# Extract hex-code data from custom string

Tags: javascript, regex, hex

For example we put the following string:
`#FF00FFNick#AA00efName`

I want to create a pattern to get the following output array

`{
[0] = {"#FF00FF", "Nick"},
[1] = {"#AA00ef", "Name"}
}`

I write the following code

```
 var reg = /#([a-f\d]{3}){1,2}(.*?)/gi;

 alert(str.match(reg));
```

But the output i get only hex-code substrings. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Maybe [`/(#[a-f\d]{6})([^#]+)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/W7kZia/1) will do? Is this format fixed and the names cannot contain `#`? Or perhaps, `(#(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2})([^#]+)`

Comment: Your formatting of the expected result is a little confusing. normally arrays are represented by [] and object literals are represented by {}

Comment: I think the example output is shown "schematically" in the question, just to show what parts of the strings should be extracted and how they should be grouped. Victor, please let know if you need a more specific output type.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
/(#(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2})([^#]+)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7kZia/2)

**Details**:

- `(#(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2})` - Group 1 capturing

  - `#`  -  a hash symbol
  - `(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2}` - 1 or 2 sequences of hex chars (case insensitive due to `i` modifier)
- `([^#]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ chars other than `#`.

Demo:

```js
var s = "#FF00FFNick#AA00efName";
var re = /(#(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2})([^#]+)/gi;
var res = [], m;
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push([m[1], m[2]]);
}
console.log(res);
```